# Open Google Extension as Application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

You can open extensions as applications using the GUI, but I cannot find the settings for it. They used to be under Chrome://Extensions, but the setting is not there any more.

You can also have the extension export a shortcut in the interface, but I just cannot find it.

Comment: I've re-tagged the question because extensions aren't apps so they can't have this UI and never could. Just because an app was/is listed in chrome://extensions doesn't make it an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99:

1. Go to Chrome://apps
2. Right click your app and select App Info
3. Select the drop down and press "Open as Window"
4. Close the popup
5. Go back and right click on your App
6. Click "Create Shortcuts..."
7. Select the checkboxes of where you would like the shortcuts (Desktop, Start Menu, Pin to Taskbar)
8. Press "Create" Button